# Using AWS Amplify allow access to an owner restricted model from a Lambda function using an API key

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I have a model that is restricted to an owner currently. We need to be able to access and update all models from a background lambda process. This is currently possible when the model is set to public using and API key.

In production it has to be owner restricted. I have the below code that I have adapted from the docs.

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/setup-auth-rules/q/platform/ios/#multiple-authorization-types-priority-order

Can anyone see any issues here or help with the best way to proceed?

```
type YourModel
 @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
        { allow: owner }
        { allow: private, provider: apiKey }
    ]
) {
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Having same issue. Did you ever find a solution?